# What is the equivelant of add-data (Pyinstaller) for Nuitka?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, pyinstaller, nuitka

I am trying to compile a python file with Nuitka in stead of Pyinstaller. Everything is going great except for the facts that I do not understand how I should add another data file to the python file.

**The problem**

If I want to add an image to my python file in Pyinstaller (in Windows) I would do:

```
wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python27/pyinstaller.exe --add-data "/root/Downloads/car.jpg;." --onefile --noconsole --icon /root/Downloads/icon.ico pythonfile.py
```

Now if I would open this exe file I would run the python file and open the car.jpg file.

I want to do something similar using Nuitka. When I looked at the documentation of Nuitka I saw that I probably needed to use the `--include-data-file=<source>=<target>` argument.

I tried this and it gave no errors, but when I open the created exe file, it does not open the given file. All the other arguments worked as I wanted, so only the --include-data-file argument does not give the wanted result

This is the Nuitka command I tried:

```
.\python.exe -m nuitka --mingw64 .\pythonprogram.py --standalone --onefile --windows-icon-from-ico=pdf.ico --windows-disable-console --include-data-file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\*.pdf=mypdf.pdf
```

**My question(s):**

- Am I using the correct argument?
- Is this even possible with Nuitka?
- How would I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when encountering unexpected behaviour in Nuitka (in this case, you'd expect a file to open, which it didn't) I highly recommend removing the `--windows-disable-console` argument and observing the terminal output; without it debugging the compiled program is virtually impossible. You can also get a lot of information by analyzing Nuitka's output during transpiling and compilation (for example, there may appear a warning informing you about including numpy's plugin in order to add support for the numpy module).

Now, moving on to your questions:

> - Am I using the correct argument?

Yes, argument `--include-data-file=<source>=<target>` is correct if what you want is to embed **one** file.

What is however very important when it comes to programs compiled with `--onefile` argument is [how the files are loaded internally](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#onefile-finding-files), in the .py files.

I feel like the best thing I can do is show an example of my own (I'm using [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) for my project, but this way of loading files should work in any circumstance):

```py
    import os
    import pygame
    
    
    def load_file(file_name: str) -> str:
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)
    
    
    image_1_sprite = pygame.image.load(load_file("textures/image_1.png"))
```

I would then use Nuitka as such: `python -m nuitka --onefile --include-data-dir=../workingdir/textures=textures main.py` or, if you want to include just one file, `python -m nuitka --onefile --include-data-file=../workingdir/textures/image_1.png=textures/image_1.png main.py`, where `workingdir` is the directory in which `main.py` resides (I recommend using relative paths to make the repository portable, because if someone were to download your source code and save it, for example, on the D:\ hard drive - the executed command would fail).

Answer (score 1):

A pathlib alternative to @chubercik's `load_file` (which I would call `rel_to_abs_path`, perhaps) would be:

```
def rel_to_abs_path(rel_path: str) -> Path:
   # Accepts a relative path (assumed correct) and returns an absolute path.
   return Path(rel_path).resolve()
```